# How to edit the content of a custom wordpress post type using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, tinymce-4

I want to edit the content of a custom post type in WordPress.
I am able to edit the shown text by this line of code in javacript.

```
// $('#wp-content-editor-container textarea.wp-editor-area').append("\n some text to add in editor");
```

However, if I start editing this text on editor I am no longer able to edit it by javascript.

I know that WordPress is using TinyMCE but I do not know how to get the id of the tinyMCE for the editor that is used in post content.

Please help me find the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

what exactly you want to edit in content?
If you want to add certain common text below each post content than you can achieve it using

> wp_content filter

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content

Answer (score 0):

I found that the custom post type that I was using does not use TinyMCE and I edited the content of my editor just like this.

```
// $('#wp-content-editor-container textarea.wp-editor-area').append("\n some text to add in editor");
```

with this differences:

$('#content').val($('#content').val()+"\n\n some text to add in editor");

Actually, I was mistakenly using append method instead of adding to the textarea value.

Thank you by the way for your quick reply. My new friend.
Swapnil Ghone